# can i speed up more than _mm256_i32gather_epi32

Tags: c++, x86, avx2

I made a gamma conversion code for 4k video

```
 /** gamma0
     input range   : 0 ~ 1,023
     output range  : 0 ~ ?
   */
    v00 = _mm256_unpacklo_epi16(v0, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    v01 = _mm256_unpackhi_epi16(v0, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    v10 = _mm256_unpacklo_epi16(v1, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    v11 = _mm256_unpackhi_epi16(v1, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    v20 = _mm256_unpacklo_epi16(v2, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    v21 = _mm256_unpackhi_epi16(v2, _mm256_setzero_si256());

    v00 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(csv->gamma0LUT, v00, 4);
    v01 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(csv->gamma0LUT, v01, 4);
    v10 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(csv->gamma0LUTc, v10, 4);
    v11 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(csv->gamma0LUTc, v11, 4);
    v20 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(csv->gamma0LUTc, v20, 4);
    v21 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(csv->gamma0LUTc, v21, 4);
```

I want to implement a "10-bit input to 10~13bit output"  LUT(look-up table), but only 32-bit commands are supported by AVX2.

So, it was unavoidably extended to 32bit and implemented using the _mm256_i32gather_epi32 command.

The performance bottleneck in this area is the most severe, is there any way to improve this?

Comment: Where do the input `v0`, `v1`, `v2` come from and what happens with the result? If you just load/store these you probably won't benefit at all by the gather instruction. Different question: can you calculate the entries of your LUT with reasonable effort (i.e., just a few mutiplications/additions/shifts/...)?

Comment: @chtz v0, v1, v2 correspond to RGB values and are converted from YUV color.
After applying gamma0, other operations are performed, and it is converted back to YUV and saved.
gamma0 corresponds to the EOTF function of this link. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_quantizer)
If i simplifies it by linearly approximating, the image quality deteriorates due to an error, so it seems that LUT should be used.

Comment: Can you perhaps approximate it by 16 piece-wise linear functions? Then you could use a more efficient `pshufb`-based LUT. Or can you approximate your function by a low-degree polynomial (instead of just a linear function)?

Comment: Please post answers as actual answers, not edits to the question.  (Do that and then roll back the question edit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the context of your question is still a bit vague for me, just some general ideas you could try (some may be just slightly better or even worse compared to what you have at the moment, all code below is untested):

### LUT with 16 bit values using `_mm256_i32gather_epi32`

Even though it loads 32bit values, you can still use a multiplier of 2 as last argument of `_mm256_i32gather_epi32`. You should make sure that 2 bytes before and after your LUT are readable.

```
static const int16_t LUT[1024+2] = { 0, val0, val1, ..., val1022, val1023, 0};
__m256i high_idx = _mm256_srli_epi32(v, 16);
__m256i low_idx  = _mm256_blend_epi16(v, _mm256_setzero_si256(), 0xAA);

__m256i high_val = _mm256_i32gather_epi32((int const*)(LUT+0), high_idx, 2);
__m256i low_val  = _mm256_i32gather_epi32((int const*)(LUT+1), low_idx, 2);
__m256i values   = _mm256_blend_epi16(low_val, high_val, 0xAA);
```

#### Join two values into one LUT-entry

For small-ish LUTs, you could calculate an index from two neighboring indexes as `(idx_hi << 10) + idx_low` and look up the corresponding tuple directly. However, instead of 2KiB you would have a 4 MiB LUT in your case, which likely hurts caching -- but you only have half the number of gather instructions.

### Polynomial approximation

Mathematically, all continuous functions on a finite interval can be approximated by a polynomial. You could either convert your values to `float` evaluate the polynomial and convert it back, or do it directly with fixed-point multiplications (note that `_mm256_mulhi_epi16`/`_mm256_mulhi_epu16` compute `(a * b) >> 16`, which is convenient if one factor is actually in `[0, 1)`.

### 8 bit, 16 entry LUT with linear interpolation

SSE/AVX2 provides a `pshufb` instruction which can be used as a 8bit LUT with 16 entries (and an implicit 0 entry).
Proof-of-concept implementation:

```
__m256i idx = _mm256_srli_epi16(v, 6);  // shift highest 4 bits to the right
idx =  _mm256_mullo_epi16(idx, _mm256_set1_epi16(0x0101)); // duplicate idx, maybe _mm256_shuffle_epi8 is better?
idx =  _mm256_sub_epi8(idx, _mm256_set1_epi16(0x0001)); // subtract 1 from lower idx, 0 is mapped to 0xff
__m256i lut_vals = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(LUT, idx);     // implicitly: LUT[-1] = 0

// get fractional part of input value:
__m256i dv = _mm256_and_si256(v, _mm256_set1_epi8(0x3f)); // lowest 6 bits
dv = _mm256_mullo_epi16(dv, _mm256_set1_epi16(0xff01));  // dv = [-dv, dv]
dv = _mm256_add_epi8(dv, _mm256_set1_epi16(0x4000));     // dv = [0x40-(v&0x3f), (v&0x3f)];
__m256i res = _mm256_maddubs_epi16(lut_vals, dv); // switch order depending on whether LUT values are (un)signed.
// probably shift res to the right, depending on the scale of your LUT values
```

You could also combine this with first doing a linear or quadratic approximation and just calculating the difference to your target function.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I read the answer carefully and it was very helpful.
Currently, I am thinking about three methods vpmaddubsw(8bits interpolation), vpmaddwd(16bits interpolation), and vpmullw( 16bits slope and intercept, a*x+b ) and it seems that it can be implemented with a fairly high precision. thanks you!